# Syntax error when creating simple python program

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, indentation

Hope you are all well.

Trying to create a Python program which acts as a dictionary however now having some issues with creating an  elif statement. Im my IDLE I keep getting signs saying that my syntax is wrong for the elif, I am not quite what I am doing wrong though? I suppose it is an indentation error but what exactly is it?

```
if choice == "0":
   print "good bye"

elif choice == "1":
  name = raw_input("Which philosopher do you want to get")
if name in philosopher:
 country = philosopher [name]
 print name, "comes from" , country
else:
 print "No such term"
***elif choice == "2" :*** ***<<I am being told that I have syntax error in this elif element, what am I doing wrong)**
  name = raw_input(" What name would you like to enter")
if name not in philosopher:
    country = raw_input( "Which country do you want to put your philosopher in")
    philosopher [name] = country
    print name, "has now been added and he is from", country
else:
      print "We already have that name"
```

Comment: you can't have an elif after an else.  The order is: if, elif, else

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you fix the indentation, the if statements all go in this order for you:

```
if x:
  #do something
elif x:
  #do something

if x:
  #do something
else:
  #do something

elif x:#CAUSES ERROR
  #do something

if x:
  #do something
else:
  #do something
```

Your `elif` comes AFTER an `else` statement. You can't do this. `elif` *MUST* go between `if` and `else`. Otherwise the compiler doesn't ever catch the `elif` (Because it just ran through and did the `else` statement). In other words, you must have your if statements ordered like so:

```
if x:
  #do something
elif x:
  #do something
else:
  #do something
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are correct as to an indentation problem. Here is what I think you are trying to do:

```
if choice == "0":
    print "good bye"
elif choice == "1":
    name = raw_input("Which philosopher do you want to get")
    if name in philosopher:
        country = philosopher [name]
        print name, "comes from" , country
    else:
        print "No such term"
elif choice == "2" :
    name = raw_input(" What name would you like to enter")
    if name not in philosopher:
        country = raw_input( "Which country do you want to put your philosopher in")
        philosopher [name] = country
        print name, "has now been added and he is from", country
    else:
        print "We already have that name"
```

The key problem is inconsistent indentation, which makes it hard for Python to determine what you want. Until you develop your own style and have a good reason for doing otherwise, a consistent four spaces of indentation per level is a good habit. Let your editor help you indent consistently. Oh, and make sure not to mix tabs and spaces when you indent: that has a way of seeming to work for a bit and then coming back and biting you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to put your `if name in philosopher`...`No such term"` section inside of the block beginning `elif choice == "1":`.  If so, you need to indent one additional time in order for Python to properly group your `if`, `elif` and `else` statements.

```
if choice == "0":
    # code
elif choice == "1":
    if name in philospher: # indented twice; can only run if choice == "1"
        # code
    else:
        # code
elif choice == "2":
    # code
# rest of code
```